# How do we Change PropertyName of Linq expression?

Tags: linq, lambda, azure-cosmosdb, jsonserializer

I have Linq Expression as below, which executes on DocumentDB SQL API on CosmosDB database.

```
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.SystemID== "123");
```

When I execute it to the context it by default generate SQL statement like below.

```
select * from [Table] where SystemID == "123"
```

But Expected query is below

```
select * from [Table] where id == "123"
```

But My Database table has a column named `id` and the Model property has name `SystemID`.
How can I put serialization logic to resolve that property name?

*Note: I don't want to use AutoMapper.*

Comment: Is this default or expected select * from [Table] where id == "123"??

Comment: This is expected, my mistake let me correct my question

Comment: I used to be doing something similar for [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) in order to add an extra expression. Check the methods in [ExpressionExtensions.cs](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/blob/develop/Cosmonaut/Extensions/ExpressionExtensions.cs). You can potentially override the parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `[JsonProperty("id")]` attribute on your property will make the LinqToCosmosSQL provider to take it into account and translate it to `id`.

Comment: This is correct, however this fix will serialize my api response and rename property to id which I don't want. I want to use SystemID at fronend side.

Comment: Well you can't really have your cake and eat it too. Your best option would be to use the SQL itself.